# Git submodule with no name and other issues

Tags: git, git-submodules

I was following some (rather disjointed) tutorial online for working with Git submodules, since it was my first time.

`git submodule` always spits out a long list of unrelated paths (probably `PATH` env?) for no immediate obvious reason, but there is a much worse issue:

```
Xkeeper@RECYCLEBIN4400 /F/_secret/Kushura (master)
$ git submodule sync
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'D:\Programs\Git/libexec/git-core;D:\Programs\Git\libexec\git-core; <long list of directories omitted...>'
Synchronizing submodule url for ''
Synchronizing submodule url for 'hump'
$
```

I cannot figure out why it is reporting no name, because both `.gitmodules` has it named properly:

```
$ cat .gitmodules
[submodule "HardonCollider"]
        path = HardonCollider
        url = git://github.com/vrld/HardonCollider
[submodule "hump"]
        path = hump
        url = git://github.com/vrld/hump
```

At the same time, `.git/config` has a phantom submodule that won't go away, and reappears any time I try to `git submodule sync` (even after removing it):

```
[submodule "HardonCollider"]
        url = git://github.com/vrld/HardonCollider
[submodule "hump"]
        url = git://github.com/vrld/hump
[submodule ""]
    url =
```

One problem that occurred is that the `HardonCollider` module isn't linking on GitHub properly, while the `hump` module is linking to the proper repo and commit. I cannot figure out why this is happening, either.

Outside of just nuking the repo and trying again I have no idea what to try next.

Comment: Tell me that you meant `HadronCollider` and not what you typed!

Comment: No. Many of LÖVE's modules are... creatively named. Like LUBE (networking), ANAL (animation), and, well... I really don't need to go on.

Comment: Well [there you go](http://love2d.org/wiki/Category:Libraries)! Every day's a schoolday!

Answer (score 0):

After fumbling with trying to accomplish anything, nothing worked except nuking the repo entirely and trying again.

- Editing .git/config to remove URL: didn't work.
- Editing .gitmodules: didn't work.
- Editing *module*/.git/config: didn't work.
- Doing all of the above at once: didn't work.
- Trying to re-add the submodule: didn't work.

In the end I had to restart my repo from the beginning and re-add the submodules, and it works properly now.

I still have the original copy of the repo, so if you can suggest a better answer I will accept that instead.

Answer (score 0):

The submodules functions are scripted, rather than coded in C. They are in the (identical) `git-submodule` and `git-submodule.sh` files. The code includes a number of cross checks that things are what they think they are, and quit's out if it doesn't like it.

You may be able to get some inspiration from the code and comparing it to the contents of your failing repo. I didn't get to the bottom of the code checks (I was reading it for other reasons)

In Msysgit, the source is at `C:\msysgit178\git\git-submodule` (that's my V1.7.8 copy)

[On Github here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-submodule.sh)

Answer (score 0):

This has bitten me twice, and I've been able to fix it once. The steps I took:

1. Made a list of all of the submodules I'd added or updated since last `clone` or `submodule update --init`
2. Remove one at a time, using the three step method found here: http://chrisjean.com/2009/04/20/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/
3. After each removal, commited, then
4. Cloned the project and see if the error remains.

Eventually I found a submodule which had files the working directory, was referenced in the .git folder, but *was not in the .gitsubmodules file*. I removed it everywhere and things were back to normal.

Extra note: I was using msysgit and getting that huge list of paths, but when I cloned on my remote test server (linux box on shared hosting) it gave much more useful errors. Can't remember exactly, but it was something like `no submodule mapping found in [the exact name of the submodule I was looking for]`.